# Angular js on input type change render list data from HTTP request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am stuck with minor issue. 
I want to render list of data from api call, on input type change event.
What my app does is, when user start typing in input type, onchange event is triggered, based on that, I want to return data from api call. So that I can give autosuggestion and let user select that data.
Basically its same like how google place autosuggest work. I just want to customize that in my own list view.

```
<ion-content ng-controller="Googleplacesuggestion">
 <h1>Search</h1>
 <label class = "item item-input">
 <input type ="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="getGooglePlaceSuggestionAutocomplete(search)"
        class="search-query" id="address_search" placeholder="Search">
 </label>
 <ul class="unstyled">
 <li ng-repeat="data in returnedData">
 <span> {{ data }} </span>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

this is my controller
        `.controller('Googleplacesuggestion',function($scope,$http){
     $scope.getGooglePlaceSuggestionAutocomplete = function($scope){
     console.log($scope);
     $scope.returnedData = [
       {text:'learn angular', done:true},
      {text:'build an angular app', done:false}
       ];`

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have moved the code from your comment to the question body.  You should edit your question with code rather than add the code in comments, since comments are not permanent and cannot be formatted.  Also, you only included some HTML here, you did not include any of the JavaScript which explains the code logic.  Please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @LucasWatson 
i have added code sample that I did.

Answer (score 0):

search something about `debouncing` this is technique to wait some time before doing some job, or super easy way to check string length

Comment: this doesn't feel like a complete answer to the question.  This might have been more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Better to post your code but here I would suggest based on my understanding. `onchange` event callback is from Javascript and is an Asynchronous from which Angular is unaware of so in your callback, wrap the code inside the function in the `$timeout(function() {})` method call which will tell Angular that something has changed.

For example:

```
<input type="text" onchange="valueChanged()" />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.valueChanged = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
          /// your code
    });
};
```

Another best option which is recommended to use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive of Angular, in this way you don't have to wrap your code inside the `$timeout` service.

Also, there are various libraries out there which provide your autocomplete code. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead is one of them if you are using BootStrap.

Comment: don't do this;  use `ng-change`.  However, this might not even be the problem the user is having, since they didn't really provide much context....

Comment: Thanks @Claies, I was updating the same.